# Minimal Ideals In LA Semigroup

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, semigroups, inverse-semigroups, generalized-inverse

Theorem. For each ideal $I$ of an LA-semigroup $S$, there exists a minimal prime ideal of $I$ in $S$.

can any one show the above result for me. I, will be very thankfull.

Comment: Please give the definition of a LA-semigroup.

Comment: A groupoid (S,.) which satisfy left invertive law, that is,  (ab)c=(cb)a for all a,b,c in S.